# Android uncaught exception at changing tab

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-tabs

I have a problem with my tab-layout-app, which is a little bit complicated to explain.

I have 3 tabs - when I click on tab1 or tab2 everthing's working fine - but when I click on tab3 and then on tab1 or tab2, the app crashes with following error:

```
W/dalvikvm(3719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e2c438)
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but before the crash following error occurs:

```
E/dalvikvm(3719): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 600K, 28% free 10127K/13955K, paused 17ms+14ms, total 63ms
```

How can I find out, what exactly the problem is?

Here is the TabsPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Map fragment activity
        return new MapFragment();
    case 1:
        // List fragment activity
        return new ListFragment();
    case 2:
        // Settings fragment activity
        return new SettingsFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
 }
```

and here is the Fragment class (Tab3):

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    return rootView;        

}
}
```

and here is whole error-log:
01-02 19:47:07.409: E/Trace(7227): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-02 19:47:07.439: W/dalvikvm(7227): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
01-02 19:47:07.689: W/System.err(7227): Invalid int: ""
01-02 19:47:07.699: W/dalvikvm(7227): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
01-02 19:47:07.979: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7227): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-02 19:47:08.359: I/Adreno200-EGL(7227): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
01-02 19:47:08.359: I/Adreno200-EGL(7227): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
01-02 19:47:08.359: I/Adreno200-EGL(7227): Local Branch: 
01-02 19:47:08.359: I/Adreno200-EGL(7227): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
01-02 19:47:08.359: I/Adreno200-EGL(7227): Local Patches: NONE
01-02 19:47:08.359: I/Adreno200-EGL(7227): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING
01-02 19:47:08.749: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3635K, 32% free 9534K/13955K, paused 14ms+7ms, total 143ms
01-02 19:47:08.819: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 153K, 33% free 9470K/13955K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 47ms
01-02 19:47:08.979: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 733K, 31% free 10173K/14663K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 46ms
01-02 19:47:09.069: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 314K, 32% free 9977K/14663K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 57ms
01-02 19:47:09.199: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 575K, 30% free 10357K/14663K, paused 4ms+13ms, total 43ms
01-02 19:47:09.289: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1141K, 32% free 11460K/16839K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 62ms
01-02 19:47:09.359: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1274K, 37% free 10642K/16839K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 52ms
01-02 19:47:09.449: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1050K, 37% free 10629K/16839K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 55ms
01-02 19:47:09.639: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1323K, 38% free 10441K/16839K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 63ms
01-02 19:47:09.759: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1048K, 38% free 10442K/16839K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 38ms
01-02 19:47:09.849: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1067K, 38% free 10583K/16839K, paused 13ms+14ms, total 53ms
01-02 19:47:09.949: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1099K, 37% free 10641K/16839K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 63ms
01-02 19:47:10.059: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1124K, 37% free 10681K/16839K, paused 13ms+15ms, total 75ms
01-02 19:47:10.199: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1219K, 37% free 10740K/16839K, paused 13ms+15ms, total 88ms
01-02 19:47:10.659: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 740K, 34% free 11125K/16839K, paused 13ms+18ms, total 87ms
01-02 19:47:11.139: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 895K, 33% free 11361K/16839K, paused 12ms+16ms, total 73ms
01-02 19:47:11.499: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1198K, 34% free 11262K/16839K, paused 14ms+16ms, total 77ms
01-02 19:47:11.849: E/dalvikvm(7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 810K, 32% free 11587K/16839K, paused 13ms+20ms, total 99ms
01-02 19:47:17.409: W/dalvikvm(7227): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e2c438)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the full log trace

Comment: Dude go to http://pastebin.com/ and paste your all logcat there and give us a link..If you dont post it here :)

Comment: Can't help without seeing code that executes when the third tab is accessed.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through your code and see if you can find out where this issue is occuring?